# procedure gets persons name by age

Tags: sql-server

I need to write procedures that get age of two persons and select from the table the first name and last name of all persons within the age

Is this code will working?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getEmployeeRange
@v_ageLow int,
@v_ageHigh int

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
     @v_dateLow date,
     @v_dateHigh date
SET @d = CURDATE()

--convert age to date 

    @v_dateLow = DATEADD(year,-@v_ageLow,@d)
    @v_dateHigh = DATEADD(year,-@v_ageHigh,@d) 

SELECT firstName,lastName FROM employee
 WHERE birthDate BETWEEN @v_dateLow and @v_dateHigh
```

Comment: Stored procedure syntax varies with the DBMS, so please specify which DBMS you are using by adding the corresponding tag.

Comment: T-sql, SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script as following;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getEmployeeRange
@v_ageLow INT,
@v_ageHigh INT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT firstName,
       lastName
FROM   employee
WHERE  birthDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1 * @v_ageLow, GETDATE()) AND 
           DATEADD(YEAR, -1 * @v_ageHigh, GETDATE())
END
```